# Creating new lightning component inside another component

Tags: lightning

I am creating a new component as below and trying to prefill the form with information. This form when accessed directly has event handling where when a radio button is selected , it displays more options such as text boxes to fill. I am able to populate some of the form fields however filled data does not invoke onchange event to display the hidden fields. Is there way to display the form based on the prefilled data. Second question is how do I set selected for a picklist item which also need to be preselected.

```
$A.createComponent(
         "c:InterviewForm",
         {
             //
         },
         function(newCmp){
            if (component.isValid()) {
              //Prefill form values
              //in input text, text area, radio buttons etc
         })
```

Comment: How do you access the controller functions from the new created component?

Comment: I would look into aura method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.ja-jp.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing any necessary data into your component in the second parameter:

```
$A.createComponent(
    "c:InterviewForm",
    {
        attribute1: "value 1",
        attribute2: "value 2",
        ...
    },
    function(newCmp){

    }
);
```

Ideally, your component should be capable of detecting which values to initialize in your `aura:valueInit` handler (`<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />`). Note that the attributes must be public or global in order to access them.